# Algoritmo C. Por que a string "why" retorna e não retorna valores numéricos?

Tags: c, algoritmo, tipagem

Escrevi um algoritmo em C para escrever na tela pares ordenados de uma função, com entrada de x números inteiros.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x,i;
    x = -1;

    do{
        system("cls");
        scanf("%i",&x);

        if(x>1000 || x <=0){
            printf("Entrada Invalida.");
            getch();
        }
    }while(x>1000 || x<=0);

    //scanf("%i",&x);
    float y[x];

    for(i=0;i<=x;i++){
        y[i]= pow(i,3) + pow(i,2) +i;
        printf("(%i,%.2f)\n",i,y[i]); 
    }
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

Fiz restrições para a entrada, mas as restrições são apenas numéricas.
Acontece que, com o código anterior, se eu digitar "why" em vez de um número, obtenho o resultado esperado: "Entrada inválida".
Mas com o seguinte código:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x,i;
    x = -1;
    //scanf("%i",&x);
    float y[x];

    for(i=0;i<=x;i++){
        y[i]= pow(i,3) + pow(i,2) +i;
        printf("(%i,%.2f)\n",i,y[i]); 
    }

    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

Obtenho o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que isso acontece? Por que com a restrição, mesmo que seja apenas numérica, o resultado é "Entrada inválida"? Por que quando não há restrição o programa calcula valores, mesmo a entrada sendo string("why")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está um pouco confuso mas realizei alguns testes e percebi o que acontece. Quando você digita "why" no primeiro código ele pode atribuir o limite superior dos inteiros que é 2^15-1 (32767) caso você não atribua um valor à X. Isso torna o if é verdadeiro pois 32767 > 1000.

Ou como "why" é um valor inválido ele mantem o valor -1, o que também torna o if verdadeiro pois -1 <= 0.

O código que eu usei para testar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv){

    int x; // Saídas: 32767, 32766, 32765 ...
    // int x = -1; Saídas: -1, -1, -1
    scanf("%i", &x);

    printf("%i\n", x);

    return 0;        
}
```

Uma boa maneira de ver como as coisas acontecem é usar printf em diferentes lugares para saber como andam os valores (Ou outra estratégia de debug mais sofisticada). Tenta dar uma arrumada nesse código porque aqui ele não deu essa saída.

Comment: Saída de um programa que lê um numero inteiro e o escreve como float:
 {why --> 2686792.000000}. Ao digitar "why" ele imprime esse número.

Comment: a primeira parte da sua resposta esclarece o fato da condição ser respeitada. Se "why" é equivalente a 26786792 então é maior que 1000. Tentei votar na sua resposta , mas só tenho 6 pontos no site.